Vinyl Records as a long-term investment? Sell 20 years later at a big profit
I bought a beginner's record player and accessories last year. It was a very expensive affair.
I've now put the record player in the cellar and am back with Homepod as hardware and music from Torrent sites. Using the record player was far too cumbersome for me. I prefer digital. It's much easier to use and Torrent Trackers are also retro in 2024.
During my very short time as a record collector, I noticed that almost all older Rammstein were only very expensive to buy on second hand market.
I now want to buy a lot of Rammstein records, store them in the cellar for about 20 years and sell them very expensively. In other words, like a stocks market, I want to store records in the cellar as an investment.
How realistic is my plan and how much profit will I make in 20 years with hardly available Rammstein records?

Vinyl is only popular right now for nostalgia reasons among those who were young in the 70s and 80s, who are also more likely to have a good financial situation. Younger generations tend to not understand what that scratchy old stuff is good for. There's something like that for every generation, so if you want something that's valuable in 20 years, hoard whatever the kids like right now.

As for Rammstein they didn't become world famous until late 90s and back then vinyls were already completely dead - literally nobody would have bought vinyls back then. So "old Rammstein vinyls" is mostly some manner of retro fabrication. I guess the oldest Rammstein stuff before they got famous date back further though, perhaps even to the vinyl era.

As with anything else, price is a function of supply and demand, and collector's markets are notoriously subject to trends and bubbles. In terms of vinyl, collectors are usually interested in original issues, although sometimes there will be a limited edition reissue especially designed to appeal to collectors.  A mass-market reissue of a classic band is unlikely to ever be worth much more than the cover price. It doesn't have the cachet (appeal to collectors) of an original, so demand isn't there, and since it's not a limited edition, there is plenty of supply.
If you're buying already expensive records--original issue Rammsteins for instance--the supply is limited, but you're betting on demand staying strong. The current price is probably driven by hardcore Rammstein fans. Will there be more or less of those in 20 years? It's also worth noting that Rammstein debuted in the CD era, so relatively few of their fans are likely to have sustained nostalgia for the vinyl experience (nor were their recordings likely optimized for vinyl).
In short, I would say this is a terrible investment strategy. If you enjoy the music, buy it and listen to it. If you don't, don't. In 20 years it's just as likely to be completely worthless as extremely valuable, and if you're keeping it in the cellar all that time, it might not be in good condition by the time you dig it up, anyway.
